# Managing assets for two different Url's

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, web

Hi i have my same scripts and images to be loaded and I am loading them relatively to my url like `info/read`. Now i want to access the same images and scripts using the different url like `diff/info/read` with out changing the file. Is there any way, can I use htaccess?

Comment: Use absolute path for loading your assets ..

Comment: @SyedQarib it isnt possible